# Swift 3: Instance member 'CognitoPoolID' cannot be used on type 'Constants'

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-cognito, auth0

I haven't been able to solve this problem on Xcode.

Here is how the Constants are defined

```
struct Constants {

let AWSAccountID = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
let CognitoPoolID = "arn:aws:XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX:XX-XXXXXXXXX-X:XXXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXX/XX-XXXXXXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
let CognitoRoleAuth = "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:XXXX/XXXXXXX_XXXXXXXX_XXXX" 

}
```

The main problem is on this line

```
let provider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(...
        identityPoolId:Constants.CognitoPoolID.value,...)
```

The error that I receive when I try to build and/or run a code analysis gives me the following compiler error.

> Instance member 'CognitoPoolID' cannot be used on type 'Constants'

Here is the code from the provider declaration all the way down to the end.

```
// This specifies AWS connection parameters.
    let provider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider (regionType: .apNortheast1,
                                                 identityPoolId: Constants.CognitoPoolID.value,
                                                 unauthRoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:XXXX/XXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXX_XXXX",
                                                 authRoleArn: Constants.CognitoRoleAuth.value,
                                                 identityProviderManager: Constants.AWSAccountID.value);

    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.apNortheast1, credentialsProvider:provider);

    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration(configuration)

    // Set out the Auth0 URL here which is the same Open ID Connect Provider URL.
    provider.logins = ["marcadian.au.auth0.com" : idToken]

    provider.getIdentityId().continue({ (task:AWSTask!) -> Any? in

        self.provider.refresh()

        if (task.error != nil) {
            // Failed Error Handling code goes here.

        } else {
            // User has logged in successfully.

        }
        return nil
    })

    // User has dismissed the Lock View Controller.
    controller?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

}
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Well, I have tried to add the data that I want directly into the method without the constants file. But I would appreciate if you could give me a solution.

Comment: Well yes I would like help then please.

Comment: So my answer was right. You should have said `static let`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message `Instance member 'CognitoPoolID' cannot be used on type 'Constants'` means that you are applying `CognitoPoolID` to the name of a *class* or *struct*, `Constants`, but it is an *instance* property. If you meant this to be a class or static property, you needed to declare it with `class` or `static`.

So, in your case, you have said:

```
struct Constants {
    let AWSAccountID = // ...
    let CognitoPoolID = // ...
    let CognitoRoleAuth = // ...
}
```

You should have said:

```
struct Constants {
    static let AWSAccountID = // ...
    static let CognitoPoolID = // ...
    static let CognitoRoleAuth = // ...
}
```

Just make that change. Now your code will compile (and work) correctly.

Comment: Well then that sort of cleared the problem but now I am getting another error as follows:

Comment: > Value of type 'String' has no member 'value'

Comment: Just delete the `.value` part. You never needed it. I can't imagine what you thought it was for. These things are strings, which is just what you want them to be.

Comment: no swift 3 this will bomb.. static properties may only be declared on a type